# php settype() isn't converting to integer, just for boolean

Tags: php

i'm trying to convert a **string** variable to a **int** varible, but when i use  it returns me **boolean**. Look down my code:

```
$withdraw = $_POST["withdraw"];
echo gettype($withdraw);
//string
$withdraw = settype($withdraw, 'integer');
echo gettype($withdraw);
//boolean
```

can someone show me a way to fix it, please?

Comment: Why don't you just go read up on how it works in the manual?!? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php Quote: _"Return Values:
Returns true on success or false on failure."_ And the examples there should make it absolutely clear, that this modifies the variable you pass as argument.

Comment: You first need to validate, then you can simply use `(int)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks man, its just that what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the strings to numeric primitive data types:

`$num = (int) "10";`

example

```
$withdraw = $_POST["withdraw"];
$withdraw = (int)$withdraw;
```

OR

`$num = intval("10");`

example

```
$withdraw = $_POST["withdraw"];
$withdraw = intval($withdraw);
```